# Inject dependency service to parent class in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have class `parent` and `child`. The `child` class extends `parent`. I need to `@Inject` injectable class `service` to `parent` because all `child`'s using it. How I can do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't inject a dependency into a parent class because Angular does not instantiate it for you. It creates an instance of your child class, which effectively initialises the parent class too (this isn't terribly accurate, as classes are just syntactic sugar, but it's suitable for this discussion).

One common solution is to just set up the child classes to be injectable and then pass the dependencies up using `super`. e.g.:

```
class Parent {
    constructor(protected someService: SomeService) { }
}

@Injectable()
class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(someService: SomeService) {
        super(someService);
    }
}
```

If `Parent` doesn't actually need the dependency itself, you're better off just using `@Injectable()` on your child classes, which could have their own private reference to the dependency.

Comment: This answer is better since the code example uses the Angular conventions to inject the service (by creating the protected someService of type SomeService) in the constructor paramters both in the Parent and Child class.

Answer (score 9):

You can inject any service or class from parent with `Injector` class, you need to inject the `Injector` class from child and pass it to the parent by `super(injector)` so parent can inject your reusable services from the injector coming from child.

**Parent class :**

```
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {

    protected myService: MyService

    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        this.myService = injector.get(MyService)
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('ngOnInit from Base');
    }
}
```

**Child class :**

```
export class AppComponent extends BaseComponent {

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    super(injector)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit()
    this.myService.getUsers()
  }
}
```

Using this way you do not want to inject each services from child to pass one by one to parent, the above way is more efficient to inject from parent.

Comment: This sounds like the accepted answer, but with extra steps. Do I get any advantages passing the injector around instead of just passing the injected instance of my service ?

Comment: @NicuSurdu This approach is a bit more flexible, because adding new dependencies doesn't require changing both constructors. As I see it, the main downside here is the violation of the [Explicit Dependencies Principle](https://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid repeatedly passing either the injector or the injected instance from the child class to the parent class, you can use this solution instead.

Create a class with a single static property:

```
export class AppModuleServices{
    static injector: Injector;
}
```

Then set the injector's value in the module where your service gets created:

```
import {Injector, NgModule} from '@angular/core';    
@NgModule({
      providers: MyService
    })
    export class AppModule {
      constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        AppModuleServices.injector = this.injector;
      }
    }
```

As long as the module has been instantiated, you can now use the static injector in any class and retrieve any of the module's services:

```
export class MyParentClass {
  private myService: MyService;

  constructor () {
     this.myService = AppModuleServices.get<MyService>(MyService);
  }
}
```