# Pass value received from service injected to parent's constructor to child component

Tags: angular

What is the Angular way to inject service to both child and parent? Initial idea is to set and share class field to all child componentss. I'm getting error `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0` on the child components. I found [approach to make child `@Injectable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847981/inject-dependency-service-to-parent-class-in-angular) but it breaks `@Component` behavior.

```
@Component({})
export class ParentComponent{
   protected value: any;
   constructor(someService: SomeService){
      this.value = someService.someValue;
   }
}

@Component({})
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent{
   constructor(){
      super();//ERROR: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0
      console.log(this.value);//I expect child to have this as well
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have injected same service to you child also( **basically you are doing inheritance i.e. parent-child class relation ship that is OOD)**

```
@Component({})
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent{
   constructor(someService: SomeService){
      super(someService);//ERROR: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0
      console.log(this.value);//I expect child to have this as well
   }
}
```

just for the note : here you are not creating childcomponent you are exending i.e. inheriting parentcomponent and extends it.

---

if you want it to **parent-child component relationship (in terms of html i.e. child tag under parent tag)** , than you should not extend you parent in child (there is no need of inheritance) , so your code will be like this

```
@Component({})
export class ParentComponent{
   protected value: any;
   constructor(someService: SomeService){
      this.value = someService.someValue;
   }
}

@Component({})
export class ChildComponent {
   constructor(someService: SomeService){
      super();
      console.log(this.someService.value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `@Input and @Output` decoretor

this link will help you

- https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-2-components-inputs-outputs/
- [https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2](https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-2-components-inputs-outputs/)

Comment: its inheritance not parent child

Comment: I dont need @Input. I need to inject service to parent and get the value from that service. but I'm getting errors on childs who are using `super()` - because parents constructor expects 1 argument (actual service injection)